# Magento 2 - Add Footer Newsletter Signup to Content Block in CMS

Tags: magento2

I need to move the Newsletter Signup from the footer into a Content Block I've created in the backend of my Magento 2.1.3 installation.

In Magento 1 you could use the code below but this appears to be no longer the case using Magento 2

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Was wondering if anyone had a solution that could help. The site I'm developing is china.testdev.tech and the newsletter signup needs to go into the blue box in the middle of the homepage content.

Thanks in advance.

Kev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In magento-2 To call the particular phtml file, You need to used this code.

```
{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="home.form.subscribe" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thanks Dhiren. Worked perfectly. Spent all afternoon yesterday trying to solve this. Appreciate your help.